# File copying times out Single User mode mac

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, cp

I have an old 2009 MacBook that recently crashed. I can't boot into safe mode, but I can boot into Single User mode, verify my disk, and mount a USB drive and copy files to that USB. However, my problem is that transferring large amounts/numbers of files times out and doesn't allow me to get all of my files back. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: How are you transferring the files exactly?

Comment: Using "cp -av /Orig/path /New/path" or "cp -R /Orig/path /New/Path"

Comment: A firewire (1394) disk may offer your better performance for bulk transfers like this.  You can also try rsync or copying smaller portions of the filesystem at a time.

Comment: I'd second the `rsync` option.

Comment: Thanks so much for suggesting the `rsync` option, everything is going mostly fine now, minus trying to copy files from areas with bad sectors. :)